# How to force stylesheet to load before anything else in header?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

I need a stylesheet to be added to the header before anything else.  That means before any styles or scripts that are automatically added by any of the plugins I'm also using.

I figured I could add this stylesheet with wp_enqueue_script, but I'm not sure how to force it to be loaded before other stylesheets or scripts that I do not have control over.

Thanks.

*This is for a theme which I need to add a stylesheet to.  This is not for a plugin I'm building.

Comment: Is this for a plugin or a theme? Is it safe to assume that there are no dependencies for this stylesheet?

Comment: When you hook the enqueue script, make sure your priority is 1 (which means it loads first). https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag that you want to call to execute your function is the [`wp_head()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) with a priority of `1`.

In your child theme's [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php) file, add the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_239006_style', 1 );
function wpse_239006_style() {
    wp_enqueue_script();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `wp_head` is used here instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`? Also, it's worth noting that negative numbers can be used for priorities too, the maximum being `PHP_INT_MIN`. This is probably not a great idea, just sayin'. Also, the toolbar (admin bar) and dashicons are given special treatment by WP, so if the user is logged in and the admin bar is configured to show, those styles will still appear before anything else regardless of the priority.

Comment: @ethanjinksosullivan Thanks.  My stylesheet is now loading as second in the header.  For some reason the nivo slider stylesheet is still loading before it.  I even set the priority to 0 instead of 1 because at 1 it was loading further down.

Comment: @Mark.C Glad that worked. be sure to click the green checkmark next to my answer to indicate that your question has been solved

Answer (score 0):

To add stylesheet before other stylesheets, use `wp_register_style()` instead of `wp_enqueue_style()`, and then manually add your style to be first at queue:

```
wp_register_style('handle', get_template_directory_uri()."/custom.css");
array_unshift(wp_styles()->queue, 'handle');
```